# Limit of the n-root of this sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm struggling to understand why $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\sin(\frac{1}{n^2})}=1$ while $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(\frac{1}{n^2})=0.$ What causes the sequence to tend to $1$ while it's under the $n$-root?

Comment: What other $n$th root limits do you already know? E.g. do you know that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n} = 1$?

Comment: ... Caused by the $n$th root? It's in $\sqrt[\infty]0$ form or $0^0$ form, which is indeterminate. Recall that for constant $0<k<1$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]k = 1$, an example of how limit $1$ can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}{\frac1{n^2}}\right)^\frac1n\times\lim_{n\to\infty}\left({n^{-\frac2n}}\right)=1$$
The fact that $\sin\frac1{n^2}$ goes to zero *like* $\frac1{n^2}$ determines this behaviour of its $n$th root.

Answer (score 2):

Since the $\exp$ function is continuous, we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)} & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\frac{\ln\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)}{n}\right)\\\\
& = \exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)}{n}\right)\\\\
& = \exp(0) 
\end{align*}

which equals one, as desired.
Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to see it and to get more than the limit is to compose Taylor series
$$a_n=\sqrt[n]{\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}\implies \log(a_n)=\frac 1 n \log \left(\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$
$$\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\frac 1{n^2}-\frac{1}{6
   n^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{10}}\right)$$
$$\log \left(\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=-2 \log (n)-\frac{1}{6 n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{8}}\right)$$
$$\log(a_n)=-\frac {2n}{\log (n)}-\frac{1}{6 n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{9}}\right)=-\frac {2n}{\log (n)}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{5}}\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=1-\frac{2 \log (n)}{n}+\frac{2 \log ^2(n)}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Try it for $n=10$ (quite far away from
$\infty$) using your pocket calculator. The exact result would be $0.630956$ while the truncated expansion would give $0.645521$